# Why does $cM\subseteq M$ imply that $M$ is a f.g. faithful $A[c]$-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm having some trouble understanding the proof of the following proposition:

[image]

The part I'm having trouble with is  $(6)\implies (1)$. The proof provided is the following:

[image]

I don't understand why, in the last paragraph, $cM$ being contained in $M$ implies that $M$ is a finitely generated faithful  $A[c]$-module. I would show my work, but I really have no clue how this would be true. Maybe this is where we use the hypothesis that the ring has dimension $1$?

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/ and edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Also, please add the source of the proof and indicate which directions have been proven before.

Comment: At this point $(1) \implies (2) \implies ... \implies (6)$ @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: Right now I don't have time to edit the post, but I'll make the changes you suggested whenever I get some free time @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: The proof is from here: https://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math205bS10/Math205b_S10_9.pdf @MartinBrandenburg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak{m}}$I'm guessing this is ripped from Atiyah-Macdonald. I didn't really follow their suggestion myself, so here's my alternative.

View $\m$ as an $A$-module. Since $A$ is Noetherian, it is finitely generated. If $c\m\subseteq\m$ then $c$ defines an $A$-module endomorphism of $m$. By (a variant of) Nakayama's lemma, multiplication by $c$ satisfies a certain characteristic polynomial. That is, there are some $a_i\in A$ and some $k$ such that multiplication by $c^k+a_1c^{k-1}+\cdots+a_k$ kills $\m$. As $A$ is hypothesised to *not* be a field (dimension is nonzero) $\m$ is nonzero and because $A$ is a domain / $Q(A)$ exists and is a field, it follows $c^k+\cdots+a_0$ is genuinely zero. But then $c$ *is* integral over $A$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Is the variant of nakayama lemma that you speak of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Yes but I decide not to call it that since Atiyah-MacDonald essentially called it Nakayama’s lemma and I prefer to think of Cayley-Hamilton as a collection of stronger statements in the special case of a field